# Unable to ping VM in a different subnet residing in the same VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a VPC.

Within that VPC, I have `subnetA` with a CIDR range of `10.238.232.0/27`. In the same VPC I have another `subnetB` with a CIDR range `192.168.10.0/28`.

vmA is deployed in `subnetA` and vmB is deployed in `subnetB`

```
vmA IP --> 10.238.232.9/32
vmB IP --> 192.168.10.2/32
```

When I ping vmB from vmA, the only response I have is

```
# ping 192.168.10.2
PING 192.168.10.2 (192.168.10.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Since Im logged into vmB via console, below are the messages I see on cosole

```
[95544.705578] IPv4: martian source 192.168.10.2 from 10.238.232.9, on dev ens5
[95544.712774] ll header: 00000000: 42 01 c0 a8 0a 02 42 01 c0 a8 0a 01 08 00        B.....B.......
Oct 16 20:29:07 vmB kernel: [95544.705578] IPv4: martian source 192.168.10.2 from 10.238.232.9, on dev ens5
Oct 16 20:29:07 vmB kernel: [95544.712774] ll header: 00000000: 42 01 c0 a8 0a 02 42 01 c0 a8 0a 01 08 00        B.....B.......
```

To troubleshoot, I allowed ALL traffic both ingress and egress for the VPC. I still cannot ping cross subnets.

Pinging VMs within subnets works perfectly fine.

Since I have also allowed all traffic using FW rules, why am I not able to ping the VMs cross subnet ?

Comment: Can you share more about the VM configuration? The OS, the network config,...

Comment: Can you provide what OS are you using (is it a vanilla image provided by GCP?), full "ip addr", "sysctl --system" and "iptables -L" output as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default VPC there are some [pre-polutated firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#more_rules_default_vpc) that allow internal communication between subnets, since it seems like you are using a custom VPC you need to manually create your firewall rules as needed, but since you created a permissive firewall rule (allow Ingress/Egress for all instances from ranges `0.0.0.0/0`) it should be enough.

To discard/confirm any issue within your VPC you can take advantage of ["Connectivity Tests"](https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/how-to/running-connectivity-tests) to simulate traffic between your instances and the output will give you an insight about the issue, the test result is either PASS or FAIL, in both cases you will see this flow considering many networking components (firewall rules, routes, peerings, hybrid connectivity, etc), if there is something missing in your GCP configuration you will notice it, on the other hand, if the test result is PASS then most likely the issue resides within your VM configurations, a good option would be to run a packet capture and see if packets are actually arriving your VMs and being discarded, for example, install tcpdump and run the following command in vmB (modify it as needed):

```
tcpdump -i ens5 src 10.238.232.9 icmp
```

If packets are being discarded check your iptables and network configuration, as suggested in the comments the output of commands `iptables -L` and `ip route` could be useful.